# Jenkins Pipeline read from yaml

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I read data from YAML file that is read in one stage and use it in another stage or outside the stage?

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    MY_ENV_VAR1 = 'VALUE1'
  }
  parameters {
    string(name: 'DEPLOY_ENV', defaultValue: 'staging', description: 'Environment to deploy on')
    booleanParam(name: 'DEBUG_BUILD', defaultValue: true, description: 'Debug the build')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Stage1') {
      steps {
        script {
          def datas = readYaml file: 'release.yml'
          echo "Got version as ${datas.version} "
        }
        echo "Deploying to ${params.DEPLOY_ENV} with debug=${params.DEBUG_BUILD}"
      }
    }
    stage('Stage 2') {
      steps {
        sh 'run.sh datas.version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access the ${datas.version} inside steps of `Stage 2` that was fetched in `Stage 1`.

I want to keep my pipeline definition as declarative as possible. 
If i read the [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#Steps) correctly, the script section can only be added within a stage. I tried this on the global pipeline level but got an error `Undefined section "script" at line 10`.

I added just `datas = readYaml file: 'release.yml'` at the pipeline level but get an error saying `Not a valid section definition: "datas = readYaml file: 'release.yml'". Some extra configuration is required line 10, column 3.`

What would be the correct way to reading the file once and then using that read data in any of the stages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems I need a `node` section around the`readYaml` code. Then I can access the `${datas.version}` in all the stages.

```
node {
  datas = readYaml file: 'release.yml'
}
pipeline {

...
}
```

This is an issue being tracked [JENKINS-40167](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40167)

Answer (score 5):

This is just a scope problem. If you declare your variable (`datas`) in a script block, it only exists in the scope of that block.

There are 2 ways to solve this. You can explicitly declare the variable "globally" (not truly global, terms of Groovy, as I understand it) by declaring it outside of the pipeline. Or with pipeline, if you don't declare a variable in a script, but just use it, it gets created as a "global" variable.

Comment: I updated my findings for defining the `readYaml` part in the pipeline section but it seems like the plugin doesn't like it.

Comment: Doesn't like what? The syntax I gave has nothing to do with the plugin. It is basic groovy variable scoping.

Comment: The groovy code is probably fine but the issue is that the pipeline is not valid.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean by your other message. So you can declare variables outside the pipeline. I do it regularly. But apparently the readYaml is not available there, it seems. But if you just declare it outside, but then modify it in your normal stage like you were, it should work. Just add "def datas" outside your pipeline. Remove "def" before "datas" in your script{}.